# Кок посчитать, сколько дней отпуска осталось?

Tags: c#

Мне нужно посчитать, сколько у человека осталось дней отпуска. Например, он работает с `2020-05-13` по `2020-08-26`.

- Если его первый рабочий день был с 1 по 15 - он получает `2` дня отпуска;
- С 15 по 25 - `1` день;
- С 26 по 31 - `0` дней.

Дальше каждый месяц первого числа начисляется `2` дня.

Он может взять отпуск в этот период, тогда количество дней, что он взял, нужно отнять из общего числа дней отпуска.

Есть таблица с рабочими днями (1) и днями, когда он был в отпуске (3). По ней нужно почситать, сколько дней отпуска осталось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И в чем проблема? Не можете отнять одно от другого?

Comment: @Dima Kozyr, наймите репетитора по *C#*)

Comment: @Эникейщик Я не понимаю, как мне взять каждый отдельный месяц и посчитать, сколько дней было в первом месяце

Comment: @Август После таких советов пропадает желание обращаться за помощью на этот сайт..

Comment: Переделайте вопрос так, чтобы было ясно, с чем именно у вас возникли затруднения. Вроде давно уже на сайте, должен знать что к чему.

Comment: @DimaKozyr, тогда я искренне прошу у Вас прощения. но, верьте мне, однажды я тоже, будучи новичком, просил **решить за меня задачу**, то меня унизили так, что до сих пор страшно публиковать какого-либо рода вопросы, так как детская травма осталась. будьте добры, учитывайте для чего создана эта платформа и давайте вместе придерживаться общепринятых норм. *с Уважением*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Псевдокод для обхода таблицы может выглядеть примерно так:

```
month = -1
rest = 0 
for x in table:
    if x.month != month:
         if month >=0 || x.day <=15 :  
             rest +=2
         elif x.day <= 25:
             rest +=1
         month = x.month
    if x.reasonId = 3:
        rest -=1
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 0):

Если честно, я не до конца понял задачу. Но решение, думаю, будет таким:

```
DateTime[] workDays; //Рабочие дни в табличке, пусть формально она уже отсортирована по возрастанию
DateTime[] restDays; //Отпускные дни в табличке, тут уже сортировка не важна
int restCount = 0; //отпуск
DateTime tmp = new DateTime(); //Это для определения смены месяца
foreach (var item in workDays)
{
    if (item.Month != tmp.Month) //Если наступил следующий месяц
    {
        rest -= restDays.Where(d => d.Year == tmp.Year && d.Month == tmp.Month).Count(); //Вычитаем все отгуляные дни за этот месяц
        
        if (item.Day <= 15)
        {
            restCount += 2; //Если он вышел на работу до 15, то добавляем ему 2 дня отпуска
        }
        else if (item.Day <= 25)
        {
            restCount += 1; //Если он вышел на работу до 25, то добавляем ему 1 день отпуска
        }
        //Если не попал ни под одно условие, то ничего не добавляем
        tmp = item; //Зачитываем новый месяц
    }
}
```